# RXJS: Scan operator emitting single item

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have been playing around with RXJS scan operator, and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.  The desired result is not have the scan return accumulated result but rather the emitted `items` from source in case `bufferResults` is false.  What the following snippet does, is emit a single value from `items` rather than the whole array.

```
 const refreshedItems$ = items$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.bufferResults$.pipe(startWith(undefined))),
      scan<any>((acc, [src, buffer]) => {
        return !buffer ? src : acc.concat(src);
      }),
      map(([items, ]) => items),
      shareReplay(),
      tap((items) => console.warn('shareReplay', items)),
    );
```

Can anyone explain how this works exactly or if you can point me to a good article on how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistake is in this line:

```
return !buffer ? src : acc.concat(src);
```

I think you meant to do:

```
return !buffer ? acc : acc.concat(src);
```

If no `buffer` you return the accumulator `acc` directly or you concat the `src` and the accumulator `acc` and return that.